# how to create a text file or XML file in C# Smart Device Applications

Tags: .net

m new to .net
m trying to create a text file or xml file in Smart device applications..
but its exists only till application is running.
stop and run application again. have need fill data in file again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show some code, then we could help more.  Are you saving the file to the file system?  Are you opening it with TextWriter, StreamWriter, File.Open()?

Comment: str = txtIpAddress.Text.Trim();
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("\\ServerSetting");
                if (!dir.Exists)
                {
                    dir.Create();
                }
                dir = null;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
StreamWriter writer = default(StreamWriter);
writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
writer.WriteLine(str);
writer.Close();

Comment: @SiwachGaurav, could you add this to your original question, formatted as code? Do you get exceptions? Thanks